# Java project runs properly in command line (exported jar), but not using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am working on an old *awt/swing* project (not of my property) on *Solaris*.The source code and a *jar* file have been given to me. The problem occurs when I run it on *eclipse:* I am getting an error related to string parsing (parsing a string hex into integer). However, when I run it from the jar, no error happens. In fact, when I export the project as a new runnable Jar file, it runs properly.

I have already tried messing with the java version used in the project. I have configured eclipse to work only with 1.6.0_31-b04 version. Printing the system properties show that the java runtime version is the same on eclipse and on the console.

Error message on eclipse:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7003fffd03"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.decode(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

I point out: **No error is generated and everything works fine when I run exported Jar on console.**

I do not ask for a solution with such little information. I would appreciate any hypothesis you could provide me with.

Comment: When you're running it from eclipse you can use something called a debugger. Maybe you should check the arguments.

Comment: Show code and error message.

Comment: Check out your java version compiler in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from a binary file turned out to be reckless.
**In different environments converting binary data into string can return different results.**
Workaround was to use specific *charset* during reading data.

```
String strFileContents = "";
byte[] contents = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = 0;

while (dataInputStream.available() != 0) {
    while ((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(contents)) != -1) {
        strFileContents = new String(contents, 0, bytesRead, "ISO-8859-1");
    }
}
```

Now running project in eclipse and from jar file on any system gives the same results.